# Citation in LaTeX

Tags: biblatex

My citation

```
\cite[4.1.4]{RobinsonACourse}
```

gives the following:

> [43, p. 4.1.5]

I don't want the letter "p." of page to appear here, because it is referring to a theorem: how can I do it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Biblatex it will assume that the part inside [] is a page number if it looks like one. If you write something else explicitly it will not be added, so to refer to a Theorem you could write `\cite[Theorem 4.1.5]{RobinsonACourse}` to get [43, Theorem 4.1.5].

To state that you don't want to have page numbers even though it might look like page numbers you write `\cite[\nopp 4.1.5]` to get [43, 4.1.5].

(But I'm assuming your are using Biblatex. If not it will be different.)

Comment: Yes, I'm using Biblatex (I forgot to mention it!). Thank you: you solved my problem!